# Overkill or appropriate?

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, web-applications, sensitive-data

I asked this question on the security boards first and received no traction so I figured I would turn to old reliable...

I have come across a web application that a company has asked me to rebuild. After all the implementation is said and done I will deploy on a private server, and the database will be on its own private server. I will manage the communication between the two with firewalls and the both of the servers data and web will be behind a load balancer. My question is this, the data that is being collected is extremely sensitive data, do I pick out the columns of sensitive information and enrypt them, because before now they have not been done so, or would this just be overkill. I want to securely store the information however I can be a bit intense when it comes to my concerns.
If the answer is no, that's great and I'm glad I asked. However if the answer is yes, does anyone know how I would go about updating the information to the newly necessary encryption.

The steps would need to be selecting all of the information, converting the columns from varchar to varbinary, encrypting the data, and finally inserting it back into the database.

The development stack for code to data I'm using is java/mysql.

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: If it's extremely sensitive data, then *yes* it should be encrypted. Perhaps google AES and Java, and use a single "key" loaded from a properties file. You might even encrypt that key with a quick and dirty software key. That way an attacker needs your Java program and the Database to decrypt the database. (or the properties file and the software).

Comment: Well, here's the question: if an attacker owns your box and accesses your database, do they also gain access to the encryption key. My feeling is the encryption you're talking about is a false comfort - in almost all cases where the data is stolen, the encryption key is also vulnerable.

Comment: @Hamish: The encryption key should of course be stored in an encrypted manner.  For example, the key can be encrypted using the login credentials of the account that will use it.  Of course, that is only as strong as the password on that account.

Comment: I appreciate the rapid response, however I am a little curious as to why there was a down vote. Secondly @Hamish, are you suggesting that if someone was to access the privately networked database server where the encrypted data was, they would also have gained access to a completely separate server where the key is stored, I understand for the most part what you are saying but the key would be on an entirely different server. In response to the first part of your question no, the key would not be hosted on the same box as the database the database is on a different server from the application.

Comment: If this is `primarily opinion-based`, I would like to see one answer that defends the opposite opinion.  IMHO this is fairly well established security practice.

Comment: @EricJ. I was indeed looking for opinions as well as best practices, I am trying to approach the situation from how I would want my information handled as well as what is the general best practice. My main reason for asking is because of the already general setting of the servers being separate and privately networked, secondly I was looking at the possibility of someone getting past that private network and obtaining the information, my final decision was made because of the information that you provided in your answer, I will encrypt the data before storing it.

Comment: @EricJ. Also I was curious I intend on building the encryption before the data is sent away from the application but is this or using the databases provided encryption the better choice?

Comment: If your database offers native encryption, it is most likely a good choice to use it.  Encryption is tricky and easy to get wrong.  Be aware of the wire between the database server and the application server(s).  I'm not sure what options MySQL provides to encrypt that communication path.

Comment: @EricJ. Firstly, it's a very limited subset of applications where the user and *only* that user can ever access the data. Maybe that's appropriate, but even so, it implies that the application has access to the users plaintext password, or some derivative, which just moves the problem around. This is the sort of thing I mean by 'false comfort'. It *seems* to be security theatre - i.e. sounds effective but is in-practise easily bypassed.

Comment: @RichardDavy yes, that's the sort of thing I mean. Just needs to be considered whether it actually makes it more security given likely scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sensitive data should be encrypted.

Bear in mind, the data is not just accessed through your application.  The backups are also stored somewhere, and one day the hard drive of the private server will be recycled.  Administrators have access to the drive, and employees of the datacenter where the private server is housed can just pull the drive out and try to read it on another computer.

A former employer once got a call from someone that bought one of our recycled PCs, just to let us know that he deleted all of our product's source code that he found on one of the "recycled" drives in that PC.  Don't let something like that happen to your sensitive data.

Comment: I would love to know from the person that voted this down just why this is not a good answer to the question.